# Does CentoOS/Yum restart services after updating them with yum?

Tags: centos, yum

Simple enough question. When I run yum update on a CentOS box, do I need to manually restart mysqld, httpd, ... and so on if they have been updated, or do they get restarted automatically?

Does anyone know where to find a source to back this up?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what's in the %post scripts of the .spec file for each package.

Generally, they don't always do so as I recall.

httpd at least does; see http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/httpd.git/tree/httpd.spec?id=ea6aac8abd84867119fd84a057daceb75e160bc1 and take a look at the %posttrans scriptlet.

Looks like that was added in Fedora 10: http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/httpd.git/tree/httpd.spec?h=f10

because of this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=491567

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'll check what each package does on CentOS. Is there a standard location for .spec files ?